# Android: change color of rectangles in a line with finger trace

Tags: android

I a developing an android app where I have small rectangles covering all four sides of screen. I used a rectangle drawable and used it in a lot of imageViews. now what I want is when a user slides their finger over these rectangles their color must change. I am using onTouchEvent for this. but firstly there are so many imageViews and the anroid studio givs me a warning. secondly the onTouchEvent doesnt seem to be working. Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: draw them in a custom `View`, adding hundreds small `ImageView`s is not a good way...

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lot, I implemented a custom View for the rectangles. But I still can't change the color of the rectangles on user touch, any ideas how I can do that ?

Comment: yeah I know how to change color what I need is change color of a rectangle when user's finger slides over it. Anyways thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: inside your `View#onTouchEvent` assign a color for each rectangle, call `invalidate()` and draw rectangles inside `onDraw`

Comment: I have multiple rectangles in my custom view. when I try to use onTouchEvent on the View it changes the color of all the rectangles in the view. what I need to do is change the color of only that rectangle that has been touched. If you could please help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made a mistake in the code. Its working now. Thanks a lot @pskink you saved me!